# How to parse json response from two different api calls in a nested for loop?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-requests

I want to parse response json from two different api calls ,but has same dictionary names with different values in a nested for loop

I was able to get from the forst api call, but failing on second api call with same dict as issues in both call but the key values are different.

```
def classtest(self):
    apione = "http://jira.com/rest/1"
    headers = {
        'content-type': "application/json",
              } 
    requestglobal = requests.request("GET", apione, headers=headers)
    responseglobal = requestglobal.text
    responseglobal = json.loads(responseglobal)
    for i in responseglobal['issues']:
         issue1 = i[key]
         print(issue1)
         apitwo = "https://jira.com/rest/2" + str(issue1)
         requesttwo = requests.request("GET", apitwo, headers=headers)
         responsetwo = requesttwo.text
         responsetwo = json.loads(responsetwo)
         for i in responsetwo['issues']:
               issue2 = i[key] + str(issue1)
               print(issue2)
               apitthree = "https://jira.com/rest/3" + str(issue1) + str(issue3)
               requestthree = requests.request("GET", apitthree, headers=headers)
               responsethree = requestthree.text
               responsethree = json.loads(responsetthree)
               for i in responsethree['issues']:
                     issue3 = i[key] + str(issue2) 
                     print(issue3)
               print("something from thirdloop")
         print("something from second loop") 
    print ("something from first for loop")
```

I want issues from all the 3 calls, as each call is interdependent

Comment: Just FYI `content-type` must be in headers

Comment: And `requests` has no `getResponse` method. and I cannot get it to JSON format either.

Comment: basically i trying to do two api calls to jira with different queries, both api calls returns  the response with issue id`s, but the issue id values are different, but the dictionary is same. for ex : api one retruns the response as [{issues{key : iss-123}}] andsecond api response is [{issues{key : iss-234}}]

Comment: u din't query `apitwo`.

Comment: if your dict has only one key, then you don't need to loop over it.

Comment: And i din't see how they are interdependent ?

Comment: if you see, issue1 is passed in to issue2 in the second loop, then issue 2 passed in to thrid loop, finally i want to print all the issues from three loops. I want issue id under issues for each api response . for ex : [{fields { issues{ key:cr-123} } }] for api 1 and second api response as same diction but key value. for ex : [{fields { issues{ key:cr-345} } }] and samething with api3 : [{fields { issues{ key:cr-456} } }]

Comment: Please show where you define `key`. If if is different for each loop, then set it before each loop

Comment: key is from api response, the response will have content as mentioned in the previous comment.